# PHPMailer funciona apenas em algumas versões

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho servidor com IIS. 
O PHP que eu utilizava é o 5.3.28 porem fui atualizar e hoje eu utilizo o PHP 7.0.0 mas o PHPMailer não funciona para essa versão, mas quando configuro o ISS para 5.3.28 o PHPMailer volta a funcionar.

Como configurar para PHPMailer funcionar no PHP 7.0.0

Answer (score 3):

Você provavelmente baixou o PHPMailer de uma fonte não oficial ou de uma fonte bem antiga, logo PHP7 mudou muita coisa, você tem que baixar o PHPMailer da fonte correta.

Baixe deste link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases a ultima, que deve ser o 6.0.2

Então no seu script php adicione:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

> Troque `path/to` pelo caminho aonde salvou o phpmailer

O resto do script deve ser mais ou menos assim:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

---

### Email sem SSL/TLS

Se a conta que vai enviar o e-mail via SMTP não tiver/suportar segurança/criptografia então você deve adicionar estas linhas:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
```

E remover esta:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```