# Como mandar emails com PHP usando a porta 587?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

Estou precisando fazer uma integração com banco de dados, onde o cliente faz o pagamento e o sistema pega estas informações como (e-mail do cliente), status da transação (aprovado), (data da transação) (data da aprovação) e cadastra no banco de dados. Depois envia um login e senha gerados automaticamente para o e-mail do cliente usando a função "mail()" do PHP.

Como faço para que o PHP cadastre o cliente no banco de dados e depois envie o login e senha gerado automaticamente para este cliente usando a porta 587 do servidor VPS?

A porta 25 é bloqueada no Brasil, por tanto a função "mail()" que usa a porta 25 simplesmente não funciona e o Gmail e outros provedores rejeitam as mensagens.

A sintaxe da programação seria a seguinte:

```
Se o pagamento aprovado: 

{ 
Cadastra e-mail do cliente no campo e-mail, 
Transforma este e-mail em senha, 
Cadastra senha no DB na tabela users, password

Altera status do cliente para "ativo" 
Cadastra data da transação
Cadastra data da aprovação
Cadastra/Altera data do próximo Vencimento

Verifica se o cliente já existe no banco de dados
Envia login e senha para o e-mail do cliente usando a porta 587 do servidor. 
Envia cópia deste e-mail para o administrador do sistema.
```

Comment: Coloque um exemplo com o código, Sintaxe da programação não é algo válido

Comment: Para que funcione bem, certifique-se de que o host seja `$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';` porque é padrão do Gmail. Habilita a criptografia TLS `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`.

Answer (score 1):

A função `mail` tem que ser configurada no back-end do teu servidor e o teu servidor tem que ter um serviço de email SMTP, em servidores Linux provavelmente use o `sendmail`, mas vou logo ao ponto que vai pois acho que a questão não é a porta e sim o tipo de envio.

Duas possibilidades:

1. você esta tentando enviar da sua máquina local, o que provavelmente não vai funcionar, teria que configurar tudo, principalmente um servidor SMTP
2. você esta enviado do teu servidor que já tem serviços de email (SMTP, PO3 e IMAP), no entanto usando a função `mail()` ele vai enviar via `sendmail`, o que não passa pela "autenticação normal", mesmo que estivesse na porta 587 ou qualquer outra porta, isso talvez não chegue no INBOX do destinatário, isso porque os proprios meios que a função `mail()` usam geralmente são barrados, a função `mail()` por muitas vezes não ter controle de limite diário de envio, tamanho e checagem geralmente acabam sendo categorizadas pelos destinatários como SPAM e que muitas vezes nem na Caixa de SPAM vai chegar, isso porque pode ter sido bloqueado antes disso, pode ter sido bloqueado por:

   - Na saída do SMTP, pois a sua própria hospedagem possui algum tipo de politica contra SPAMs
   - Na tentativa do `sendmail` com SMTP se *"comunicar"* com o servidor de destino, o que pode ser rejeitado ali mesmo.

   **Não estou dizendo que você esta praticando SPAM**, estou dizendo que politicas contra SPAM não tem como identificar se você é ou não um SPAMMER, pois este método de envio não tem qualquer maneira possível de checagem garantida.

### Então como resolver o envio de emails

Simples, mas nem tanto, enviando via SMTP autenticado por uma conta de e-mail real e de preferencia por uma porta com certificados de segurança (se tiver, for possivel), claro que não é 100% garantido, mas irá funcionar bem melhor com certeza em comparação ao `sendmail`, no caso do PHP para se comunicar com um servidor SMTP, seja outlook.com, seja gmail, seja yahoo, você pode usar o:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Como expliquei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/261314/3635

Então seguindo esta parte:

```
Cadastra e-mail do cliente no campo e-mail, 
Transforma este e-mail em senha, 
Cadastra senha no DB na tabela users, password

Altera status do cliente para "ativo" 
Cadastra data da transação
Cadastra data da aprovação
Cadastra/Altera data do próximo Vencimento

Verifica se o cliente já existe no banco de dados
Envia login e senha para o e-mail do cliente usando a porta 587 do servidor. 
Envia cópia deste e-mail para o administrador do sistema.
```

Todos 8 primeiros itens você mesmo faz, que isso é muito amplo e impossivel de responder aqui, então chegamos aos que nos interessa que é os:

```
**Envia login e senha para o e-mail do cliente** usando a porta 587 do servidor. 
**Envia cópia deste e-mail para o administrador do sistema.**
```

Esqueça a porta agora, o que importa é enviar ao cliente e ao adm, então deve ficar assim, depois de feito todos 8 items no phpmailer faça isto:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // desative isto depois de efetuar os testes
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.empresax.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'contato@empresax.com';
    $mail->Password = 'senha';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    //Email que o cliente deve ver como remetente
    $mail->setFrom('contato@empresax.com', 'Mailer');

    //Envia uma cópia oculta para o adm
    $mail->addBCC('administrador@empresax.com');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Sua senha esta pronta';
    $mail->Body    = 'Conteudo HTML da mensagem';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Claro que isso depende das configurações do teu servidor, e é provável que o teu servidor e politicas de anti-SPAM impeçam que você envie mais de 100 mensagens por dia (cada destinatário creio que conta como uma mensagem diferente).

Só pra constar, se for sem TLS e SSL, ou for TLS também, talvez a porta seja 587, mas isso é porque seja padrão do teu servidor/hospedagem, você deve consultar com eles, então se for com TLS, talvez deva ficar assim:

```
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
```

Se for sem TLS e sem SSL, então terá que fazer isto:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Mas como eu já disse, olhe a documentação da sua hospedagem (geralmente tem) ou consulte o suporte técnico para saber quais portas deve usar, geralmente é a mesma configuração que o seu cliente usa no Outlook ou Mozilla Thunder Bird.

### Se for Gmail ou Outlook (antigo hotmail)

Para gmail a configuração deve ser algo como:

```
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'emaildoseucliente@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'senha';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
```

No entanto creio que é necessário habilitar para que o Gmail permita o envio, no link: https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security

No outlook não lembro ao certo, talvez seja ainda smtp.live.com, que ficaria:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Ou talvez seja agora pelo office365 (não uso isto, me corrijam se tiver me enganado em algo):

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, sensacional sua explicação. Gostaria de saber quanto você me cobraria para criar esta sintaxe que passei na pergunta pois sou meio leigo em PHP então vejo que você possui conhecimentos bem avançados. Fico no Aguardo de um orçamento se puder me passar seu email "sem o arroba" pra evitar spammers fico agradecido.

Comment: @RodrigoPorto brcontainer@yahoo.com.br